# How to add a second git user and repository to the same project?

Tags: git

I am trying to set up a second repository for a project I am working on. The first repository is in github, the second is in gitlab, I am primarily using github, but the client wants gitlab and they gave me a completely different account for that.

Because of that I need to be able to push the same project to both of these repositories.

I know how to add a second a repository to the same project and push to it, the problem is that I cant figure out how to configure a completely different user for that repository.

When I try to push with `git push secondremotename secondremotebranchname` I just get an error saying that it cant find the repo or I dont have permission to view it, which is correct, because I do not get prompted to log into that new account.

Comment: Did you add the remote as https://… or SSH (ssh:// or git@gitlab:…)? Do you have an SSH key associated with your GitLab account?

Comment: Https, I have not created SSH key.

Comment: When using https, Git uses a *credential helper* to provide user name and password. The set of credential helpers available on your OS depend on your OS, so add that to your question here (or switch to ssh where it's much more similar from one OS to another).